# IntelliJ IDEA 2016 project change java sdk version from 7 to 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The external libraries in Project window shows that the project was using jdk7.
Then I change the jdk version in File > Other settings > Default project structure> SDKs, by adding jdk 8 from its installed location. Now java 7 is gone, but java 8 does not show up and it could not compile. Is this a bug or did I miss anything? 
[image]
if I add java 7 then it comes back in External Libraries:
[image]

Comment: check your pom, maybe you have configured to compile with java 7

Comment: @cralfaro I have used mvn command and it works fine with 8

Comment: yeah probably if you do mvn -version you will see the java version is 8 and works, but check also if java -version says is 8

Comment: @cralfaro java -version says it is 8

Comment: go to settings ->java compiler and verify your module has target as 1.8

Comment: @cralfaro every number in this view is 1.8. although I don't get what "bytecode version" mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to adjust dependencies in module itself / remove old 1.7 libraries and add from new sdk

Comment: how to adjust dependencies in module? it seems that now I can successfully remove, but fail to add. Please see the difference in pictures in question.

Comment: usually IDEA will synchronize with your pom automagically ( if you allow it )   and if not -  there is small green plus sign on the side

Comment: you were right it is the module settings. Please see my answer too. a supplement of yours

Answer (score 0):

change the module settings indeed. Right click on the module (which I understand it as project in Eclipse I guess) and click Open module settings (F4 shortcut), and on tab dependencies, change it to 1.8, originally it was blank. (If it was blank shouldn't it be using the project settings which is already configured as java 8, but no, for some reason it still use java 7)
[image]